# Provider com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory not found with JCL

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to develop an application which uses a library with a `stax-api` as a dependency. Build as stand-alone application it works fine, but when I'm trying to load JAR with dependencies assembled in my application using `JCL`, I get the following error:

```
javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory not found
at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:72)
at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:178)
at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:92)
at javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance(XMLInputFactory.java:136)
at org.codehaus.xfire.util.STAXUtils.<clinit>(STAXUtils.java:48)
at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.HttpChannel.writeWithoutAttachments(HttpChannel.java:54)
at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender.getByteArrayRequestEntity(CommonsHttpMessageSender.java:422)
at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender.send(CommonsHttpMessageSender.java:360)
at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.HttpChannel.sendViaClient(HttpChannel.java:123)
at org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.HttpChannel.send(HttpChannel.java:48)
at org.codehaus.xfire.handler.OutMessageSender.invoke(OutMessageSender.java:26)
at org.codehaus.xfire.handler.HandlerPipeline.invoke(HandlerPipeline.java:131)
at org.codehaus.xfire.client.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:79)
at org.codehaus.xfire.client.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:114)
at org.codehaus.xfire.client.Client.invoke(Client.java:336)
at eu.unicore.security.xfireutil.client.ReliableProxy.handleRequest(ReliableProxy.java:122)
at eu.unicore.security.xfireutil.client.ReliableProxy.doInvoke(ReliableProxy.java:102)
at eu.unicore.security.xfireutil.client.ReliableProxy.invoke(ReliableProxy.java:69)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.QueryResourceProperties(Unknown Source)
at de.fzj.unicore.wsrflite.xmlbeans.client.BaseWSRFClient.queryResourceProperties(BaseWSRFClient.java:372)
at de.fzj.unicore.wsrflite.xmlbeans.client.RegistryClient.listServices(RegistryClient.java:199)
at de.fzj.unicore.wsrflite.xmlbeans.client.RegistryClient.listAccessibleServices(RegistryClient.java:214)
at org.caebeans.wsrf.UNICOREModule.initialize(UNICOREModule.java:53)
... 9 more
```

It's rather strange, this class is assembled into the JAR, I can find it in archive.

Comment: You may want to remove the jcl tag as jcl is for IBM Mainframe Job Control Language

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this kind of message when application server libraries are loaded before application ones. Usually there's a setting that lets you specify the inverse order. If, as it seems, you're using Weblogic this may be achieved by inserting the following definition in your `weblogic.xml` file:

```
<container-descriptor>
  <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```

Comment: I'm using my own container to host components - and this is the problem. Also, I assemble my component into one superJAR with all the dependencies - and class `com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory` is presented there.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>stax</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```